# Is there such a phrase as "How I knew something would happen"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

Let's say you have a feeling something bad will happen. You go to the kitchen, pour yourself a glass of water, and walk back to your room. Then you accidentally drop the glass, it falls and breaks. Can you then say, "How I knew something bad would happen."? Or is there another phrase for it?

Answer (score 1):

There are many phrases used to express a premonition or an antiipation particularly of something bad.

The sentence  "How I knew something bad would happen." does not sound fully natural, however. Just remove the "How" to get:

> I knew something bad would happen.

Or more strongly

> I just knew something bad would happen.

In the form of a question one might say:

- > How did I know something bad would happen?
- > Why did I think something bad would happen?
- > Why aren't I surprised that something bad happened?

Or any of many other possible forms.